# What should be done when MediaCodec.dequeueOutputBuffer signaled INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED?

Tags: android, media, decoding

What should be done when `MediaCodec.dequeueOutputBuffer` signaled `INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED`? Just call `getOutputFormat` to and print out the new format?

Answer (score 0):

For what its worth, I believe that the new format is provided to you because you'll (probably) need it in order to correctly mux the output (using MediaMuxer), once the encoding is completed.

refer to http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/#q9 for additional info.